# A neural network runs fine on a laptop, but on laptop with GPU gives error message

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

The following code runs fine on normal laptop, but on Lambda laptop with GPU gives the following error message:
typeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU object at 0x7f0626b2c748>

If I change activation to 'relu' code runs fine on both laptops.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn import preprocessing


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(100000, 24)))
x = df.values
min_max_scalar = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scalar.fit_transform(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
df.iloc[:, -1:] = df.iloc[:, -1:].apply(lambda x: round(x))

X_train_full = df.iloc[:70000, :23].to_numpy()
y_train_full = df.iloc[:70000, 23:].to_numpy()
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train_full, y_train_full)

X_test = df.iloc[70000:, :23].to_numpy()
y_test = df.iloc[70000:, 23:].to_numpy()
y_test.ravel()


model = keras.models.Sequential()
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(23, activation='relu', input_shape=(23,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(30))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['BinaryAccuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('test_accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run code without any issues using GPU.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU, Dropout
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(devices) 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(100000, 24)))
x = df.values
min_max_scalar = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scalar.fit_transform(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
df.iloc[:, -1:] = df.iloc[:, -1:].apply(lambda x: round(x))

X_train_full = df.iloc[:70000, :23].to_numpy()
y_train_full = df.iloc[:70000, 23:].to_numpy()
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train_full, y_train_full)

X_test = df.iloc[70000:, :23].to_numpy()
y_test = df.iloc[70000:, 23:].to_numpy()
y_test.ravel()


model = keras.models.Sequential()
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(23, activation='relu', input_shape=(23,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(30))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['BinaryAccuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('test_accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Output:

```
2.7.0

[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

Epoch 1/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 9s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6938 - binary_accuracy: 0.4999 - val_loss: 0.6943 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 2/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6934 - binary_accuracy: 0.5016 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 3/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6933 - binary_accuracy: 0.5027 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 4/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6938 - binary_accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 5/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6934 - binary_accuracy: 0.5018 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 6/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6934 - binary_accuracy: 0.5018 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 7/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6935 - binary_accuracy: 0.4991 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 8/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6936 - binary_accuracy: 0.5009 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 9/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6934 - binary_accuracy: 0.5004 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
Epoch 10/10
1641/1641 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6937 - binary_accuracy: 0.5041 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5094
938/938 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6935 - binary_accuracy: 0.5013
test_accuracy: 0.5012666583061218
```